# No email notification to attendees when event is update

Tags: office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, impersonation

I am using EWS API to create and update calendar events in office365 and exchange under an impersonation account.  I would like for the attendees to get an email notification of the update but it only seems to send notifications when the originator account is used.  Is there an xml tag that I'm missing to force a notification to happen?

Im working in python without a managed API, using soap XML to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The SendMeetingInvitations attribute of the CreateItems Element will control what type of notifications that will be sent eg

```
    <CreateItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
            xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
            SendMeetingInvitations="SendToAllAndSaveCopy" >
```

Comment: I will give this a try this weekend, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

When executing the `UpdateItem` EWS operation, use the `SendMeetingInvitationsOrCancellations` attribute. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-update-appointments-and-meetings-by-using-ews-in-exchange

Comment: I'll try it out this weekend, thank you for the info